# "Isn't it Marcus said that?" - is it grammatically correct?

Tags: questions

If someone said a famous quote and claimed that it was said by a certain person and you want to correct him by saying that another person said it (let's say Marcus), how do you say it?

Is it:
"Isn't it Marcus who said that?"

Comment: "Isn't it Marcus **who** said that?" "Wasn't it your sister **who** made the lunch?"

Comment: wow, as a non native English speaker, this is helpful! Thank you so much Lambie!!

Comment: Agreed with Lambie - but you will find **that** (instead of **who**) often used in this context. **It was was the postman that left the parcel.**   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns